# How to mock a script tag in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, google-tag-manager, react-helmet

I am using `react-helmet` to include a google tag manager script tag on a particular page. It works fine but jest throws a declaration exception.

Normally I would use `jest.mock` but I can't seem to get it working for this and I can't seem to get jest to ignore that line of code.

```
   <Helmet>
          <title>{messages.title.defaultMessage}</title>
          <meta name="title" content={messages.metaTitle.defaultMessage} />
          <meta name="description" content={messages.metaDescriptions.defaultMessage} />
          <meta name="keyword" content={messages.metaKeyword.defaultMessage} />
          {/* Google Tag Manager */}
          <script id="ga-script" type="text/javascript">
            {((w, d, s, l, i) => {
              w[l] = w[l] || [];
              w[l].push({
                'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
                event: 'gtm.js',
              });
              const f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              const j = d.createElement(s);
              const dl = l !== 'dataLayer' ? `&l=${l}` : '';
              j.async = true;
              j.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=${i}${dl}`;
              f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
              f.className = 'ga-script';
              j.className = 'ga-script';
            })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-000000')}
          </script>
          {/* End Google Tag Manager*/}
        </Helmet>
```

```
<VerificationPhonePage /> equalEmailProps › encountered a declaration exception

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

      296 |               j.async = true;
      297 |               j.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=${i}${dl}`;
    > 298 |               f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
          |                 ^
      299 |               f.className = 'ga-script';
      300 |               j.className = 'ga-script';
      301 |             })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-000000')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used Google Tag Manager, but this script it seems to me just overkill on React.

You can do that :

#### before return

```js
const i = 'GTM-000000'
// "i" is not self descriptive, rename it
// but if the value never change, insert it directly in url

const src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=${i}`

// the only important code in your function
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
window.dataLayer.push({
  'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
  event: 'gtm.js',
})
```

#### on return

```html
<Helmet>
  <script src={src} async className="ga-script" />
</Helmet>
```

Comment: this is just the script that google gives you. It can be better but i need way of testing first

Comment: the problem it seems be the return of `getElementsByTagName` function. My sample don't do that. The test fail too ?

Comment: yes, that is the issue. I need to mock that in the test but how do i mock a node element?

Answer (score 0):

To simply mock the method, I achieved results in following manner (I am using Vue and jest):

Vue code:

```
created(){
        this.pushPageTitleInGTM()
    },
    methods:{
        pushPageTitleInGTM(){
            this.$gtm.trackEvent({
                event: 'Page Title', 
                category: 'Page Title',
                action: 'Page Load',
                label: '404 Page',
                value: '404',
                pageTitle: '404',
            });
        }
    }
```

Jest unit:

```
import _404 from './404.vue'
describe('@views/404', () => {
    let wrapper;
    // test set up
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallowMount(_404, {
        methods: {
            // mocking GTM 
            pushPageTitleInGTM: () => {} 
        }
        })
    })
})
```